# Use regex to retrieve string between characters

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I would like to either use a `grep` command or just know the `regex` to get the following string between the ">" and "<" characters.

string :

```
<f id=mos-title>demo-break-1</f>
```

I would like to return

```
demo-break-1
```

Comment: [Here's the regex you need.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Comment: Another way to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

suppose file `foo` contains:

```
<f id=mos-title>demo-break-1</f>
<f id=mos-title>demo-break-2</f>
<f id=mos-title>demo-break-3</f>
<a>foo testing</a>
```

You could do something like this:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /<.+id=mos-title>(.+?)<\/f>/' foo
```

Keep in mind that this would be strict as to having these matches only occur on one line.  Also, you will have to account for any deviations in the format since this is not a valid HTML parser.

Here's a more relaxed approach as far as being strict, but still not 100% HTML compliant.

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /<.+id=mos-title\b.*?>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/f>/' foo
```

Output would be as follows:

```
demo-break-1
demo-break-2
demo-break-3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper xml document like this:

```
<root>
  <f id="mos-title">demo-break-1</f>
</root>
```

you can use a proper parser:

```
xmllint --xpath "/root/f[@id='mos-title']" input.xml | \
      sed 's/[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<[^>]*>/\1\n/g'
```

With the input you have, it you are **sure** that the input format is consistent (i.e., generated) you can use sed:

```
sed 's/[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<[^>]*>/\1/g' input
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to use an XML-parser, but you could try this awk:

```
awk '$1==s{print $2}' s="f id=mos-title" RS=\< FS=\> file
```